# How to solve this optimization problem with logarithmic objective function?

Tags: linear-programming

I have this optimization problem
[image]

I have no idea how to solve it. Is Lagrange suitable for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry. We don't need to mind $t$.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Observe that the gradient of the objective function has the components $\dfrac{f_iv_jq_i}{1+v_iq_j\rho_{ij}}$ and these do not vanish. So there is no stationary point and all constraints must be saturated and you can apply Lagrange.